# How do I call a JavaScript function from an erb template?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

If you define a JavaScript function and then call it from an erb template the function does not get called. Why? Clicking this link should show an alert, but it does not.

```
= link_to "Add Sprout", new_sprout_path, remote: true
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @sprout = Sprout.new
  respond_to { |format| format.js }
end
```

Then in the template I call a function:

```
# sprouts/new.js.erb
doSomething();
```

The function is defined in my js files:

```
# javascripts/sprouts.js.coffee
doSomething = ->
  alert "yum ghum I am a new sprout."
```

The JavaScript comes back. I can see it in the console. But I see no alert. Why doesn't this not work?

I'm using Rails 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@doSomething = -> alert "yum ghum I am a new sprout."
```

or

```
window.doSomething = -> alert "yum ghum I am a new sprout." # I prefer this approach, as it's more explicit.
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me understand why my code, which doesn't use `@` doesn't work?

Comment: @user2615384 in your example, the JS function is wrapped in an anonymous function -- `(function(){ var doSomething = function(){...} }).call(this);` -- so it does not exist when your template tries to execute it. Preceding the var with an `@` is identical to `window.doSomething` and therefore makes the function "global" or more precisely, a property of the window object.

Comment: You beat me to it, Kyle. Here's my response, anyways: In CoffeeScript, variables and functions are scoped to the file they're created in in order to avoid variable collisions. (If you look at the compiled JavaScript, you'll see that your code is wrapped in an IIFE.) `@` is shorthand for `this` and if `this` happens to be `window`, then the variable will be available in the global scope. (`this` could also be a context created by an object, function, etc.) Using `window` ensures that the variable will be available in the global namespace.