# how to call a java script function in a file( xyz.js.erb ) in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, function, call

i am having the following function call and function definition in xyz.js.erb file. but the function is not calling.

```
    merge_cells();

    function merge_cells() {  

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing javascript function definition in js.erb file is not a good way. You can move that function to application.js file

Comment: when i include this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`  library in my xyz.js.erb file, then the  method is calling. but this link i added to the view page already which is got some stuff used by the xyz.js.erb file.

Comment: You can send the response using instance variable and you can use this variable on your erb template. For more understanding here is a good explanation.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595739/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-from-an-erb-template